# Cannot open a csv file from file download dialog box, IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

All,

When i try to open a csv file from my asp.net 3.5 app by clicking on the link provided, a file download dialog box appears.When i click on the open button from there , i get this eror

C:\Documents and settings\UserName\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\X9TXTM06\myfilename.csv could not be found .Check the spelling of the file name and verify that the file locationis correct?

Wjy am i getting this error? I am trying to open a file and it complains about file not found in the Temporary Internet Folder.I tried deleting the temp intrnet files.Dint work.I have IE 7 on xp professional sp3. Also i am streaming the file from the application. This happens only to some files and the rest of the files , i can open .

Please help

THank you in advance

Comment: Does it work with other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in the Expires, and Cache-Control HTTP Response headers?  It looks like you may be telling IE to expire or to not cache the document.  IE uses the cache for downloads unlike other browsers.

And is it HTTPS?  There are more conditions for HTTPS, like the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" option (i.e. it'll need to be checked to prevent the download manager from using the cache and following the cache control directives).

If you're using pragma:no-cache (you shouldn't) that will need removing too.

Comment: Thank you for youe help. This is what i have in the HTTP header and am not using https( But in QA their web site is https and they are xperiencing the same )Response.ClearResponse.ClearContent(); Response.ClearHeaders(); Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sf.FileName);  and am calling Response.End() at the end

Comment: The only additional thing I can think to try is to set the Cacheability to public.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I found this on an IBM site...

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398980

> **Cause** This issue was investigated as a product defect under APAR PK69666. It was determined to be caused by third-party limitations of
>   Internet Explorer and Microsoft Office. The specific causes of this
>   issue are:
>
> - A limitation of the content disposition header used by Internet    Explorer.
> - A limitation of the file and path length for Excel or other Office    document files. The character limit depends on the Office file type.

I'm seeing a correlation between the files giving me this problem, and the length of their file names.